# How do I send a serialized object over network stream to a tcp listener in Xamarin?

Tags: android, object, serialization, tcp, xamarin

Can someone show me a code example of how to send serialized objects back and forth from a Xamarin Android application using a BinaryFormatter instead of Json? It's going to be over WiFi inside the Server Farm.

I'm currently trying to port a simple administrative console application over to an Xamarin Android forms application. I don't understand PCL yet or it's lack of [serializable] attribute. I've heard from the guys at Xamarin that I should probably try Android specific Xamarin instead of forms. I'm new to this so I'm not sure. This will be connecting to a custom Windows Service using standard TCPListeners. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

This is an example of the type of console code that I am trying to port over.

```
    public static void HeartBeatPulseListener()
    {

        Int32 hbPort = 8002;
        Console.WriteLine("\nStarting Heart Beat Listener on Port: {0}", hbPort.ToString());
        TcpListener heartBeatListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, hbPort);
        heartBeatListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            using (TcpClient client = heartBeatListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
                IFormatter formater = new BinaryFormatter();
                HeartBeatPulse pulseMSG = (HeartBeatPulse)formater.Deserialize(netStream);
                if (pulseMSG != null) Console.WriteLine("\nPulse:{0} \n tStamp:{1}\n FROM:{2}\n Instance:{3} \n Original Unique:{4} \n Type: {5}", pulseMSG.Id.ToString(), pulseMSG.TimeStamp.ToString(), pulseMSG.A.ToString(), pulseMSG.ServerCoreInstanceId, pulseMSG.OriginalUnique, pulseMSG.Type);

                if (pulseMSG.Roles.Count() > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nRoles:");
                    foreach (string role in pulseMSG.Roles)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", role);
                    }
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("\nSum Ting Wong");
                Console.ResetColor();

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Also, I forgot the mention my primary goal is to serialize custom complex objects w/out using Json. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  SO is a Q&A site, so you'll usually get a better response if you ask a specific question.  I will say that what you're doing will probably be easier in a Xamarin Android project than trying to use Forms.

Comment: Thank you so much Jason. I didn't realize that until you said something. My mind was completely on the code and not on communicating with people. I've edited in a question.

Comment: You are looking for Serializable and ObjectOutputStream but with .NET?

Comment: I want to port the current console code minus the display to an Xamarin Android application. I want to serialize and object and send it over a network stream to a TCPListener on a windows service. Then I want to receive a serialize object on the same device on a TCP socket and deserialize it back into an object.